# SLF4J and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, logging, slf4j

Say I have:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    // SLF4J
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Animal.class);

    // ...etc.

    public void setLogger(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public Logger getLogger() {
        return this.logger;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public abstract class Dog extends Animal {
    // SLF4J
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Dog.class);

    // ...etc.

    public void setLogger(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public Logger getLogger() {
        return this.logger;
    }
}
```

Then when I execute the following code:

```
Dog d1 = new Dog();
Animal a1 = new Dog();
```

1. Will `d1` get a "Dog" logger or an "Animal" logger?
2. Will `a1` get a "Dog" logger or an "Animal" logger?
3. Is there a better/cleaner/safer way to write this code so that Dog and Animal always get the correct logger?

Comment: Thanks @Reimeus (+1) - so why wouldn't I need to `@Override` the `Dog#getLogger` and `Dog#setLogger`, seeing that its `Animal` parent has the same methods?

Comment: 1) You have 2 loggers one `logger` hides the other 2) Just Animal logger 3) Its fine the way it is - you may want to distinguish code called in Animal vs Dog. Loggers are not shared between classes as you want to be sure that each displays information relating to that particular class. Getters/setters unnecessary...

Comment: Do you really need a logger for each instance?

Comment: Sure @DaveNewton - why wouldn't you?

Comment: Why *would* you? Is been a rare occasion my logging needs haven't been met with a static logger per class.

Comment: Static logger introduces the possibility of shared state and thread safety issues. There is absolutely nothing wrong with what I'm doing.

Comment: @DaveNewton I also use loggers per instance instead of per class. See http://slf4j.org/faq.html#declared_static for more info on pro's and con's. I tend to put loggers in component objects (i.e. Spring instantiated beans) which tend to not be instantiated more than a few times (usually once) anyway.

Comment: @IAmYourFaja Did I say there was? I asked if you *really* needed a logger per instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d1` and `a1` will have both types of loggers, `((Animal)d1).logger` will be the `Animal.class` logger and `d1.logger` will be the `Dog.class`. Note you can't actually reference `((Animal)d1).logger` out side of code in Animal class since `Animal.logger` is a private field.

The same will be true of `a1` as well since its runtime type is `Dog`